# File extension added onto a f=io.open()

Tags: lua, filenames

I am having trouble naming a log file. Once you name it, I want the code itself to slap on a `.txt` extension, but how can I do this? I'm using this to name it:

```
LogName = io.read()
f=io.open(LogName, "w")
```

I tried doing `f=io.open(LogName,".txt","w")` and a whole bunch of others.

Answer (score 5):

Try [string concatenation](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.4.5) with the `..` double period operator.

```
f=io.open(LogName .. ".txt", "w")
```

However, you might want to check if there's an extension already at the end of the `LogName`, with something like this.

```
if LogName:lower():find'%.txt$' then
    -- ...
end
```